# Ajax Async: true, preciso de um exemplo

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json

Olá, quero apenas um exemplo para fins de estudo. Quero que a página fica atualizando automaticamente, para futuramente fazer chat, a página atualizar de forma assincrona e também para página atualizar em tempo real, onde outra pessoas do computador possa ver os dados ao mesmo tempo. Todo com bastante dúvida em Ajax com JQuery, por isso estou fazendo a pergunta. A minha dúvida é relacionado a função...

eu tenho o arquivo teste.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="atualizar-assincrona"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Tenho o arquivo ajax.php

```html
$(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php", // substitua por qualquer URL real
    async: true
}).done(function () {
    a = true;
});
 
});
```

Desculpe mas não sei muito bem utilizar essa função, preciso de apenas uma função simples para está atualizando os dados sem que usuário perceba. Pode ser qualquer uma, Porém entendo de JQuery mas tem poucos matérias que ensina sobre ajax.

Atualização pode ser a cada 2 segundos...

Comment: Por curiosidade, você já leu a [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) da função? Se sim, pode editar a pergunta e adicionar quais são as reais dúvidas?

Comment: Primeiramente @Alan o código do arquivo`ajax.php` não será executado, pois você está tentando executar `javascript` dentro de um arquivo `.php`.

Comment: `async: true` é o valor inicial mesmo que não o indiques. E `async: false` foi removido do jQuery porque era uma má ideia. Também não percebo a pergunta, podes explicar melhor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um exemplo simples seria criar uma função para chamar o Ajax e retornar os dados:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        setTimeout("atualiza()",2000); // Aqui eu chamo a função após 2s quando a página for carregada
    });

    function atualiza(){ // Função com Ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: "teste.php", // substitua por qualquer URL real
        async: true
    }).done(function (data) { // "data" é o que retorna do Ajax
        a = true;
        $("#atualizar-assincrona").html(data); // Aqui eu jogo o retorno do Ajax dentro da div
        setTimeout("atualiza()",2000); // Novamente chamo a função após 2s quando o Ajax for completado
    });
    }
</script>
```