# Como receber dados do ajax em um vetor?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Olá pessoal estou tentando fazer isso, porem sem sucesso:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section id="lista-filmes"></section>
</body>
</html>
```

JQuery:

```
var filmes = [];
$.get("https://www.mocky.io/v2/5ad631b32e00001000c93a96", function(data){
    data.forEach(function(filme){
        filmes.push(filme);
    });
});

$.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0108037&apikey=???`,function(data){

});
console.log(filmes[0]);
```

Os valores que recebo é `undefined`

a idéia é, quando eu consequir acumular em um vetor a requisição, eu passar para a segunda url

```
for(etc.) {
    $.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${filmes[i]}&apikey=???`,function(data)  
    });
}
```

fazer algo do tipo, pra conseguir consumir a segunda api.

Comment: Vc não consegue porque a primeira requisição é assíncrona.

Comment: como eu consigo reverter isso? oq eu devo estudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que fazer seu `for` dentro do *callback* da primeira requisição, porque ela é assíncrona:

```
var filmes = [];
$.get("https://www.mocky.io/v2/5ad631b32e00001000c93a96", function(data){
    data.forEach(function(filme){
        filmes.push(filme);
    });

   for(var item of filmes){
      $.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${filmes[item]}&apikey=???`,function(data) {
      });
   }
});
```

Mas fazer requisições em laço assim acho que não é uma boa, mas vai depender do que você esteja querendo fazer.

Mas você pode aproveitar o primeiro laço `forEach` em vez de fazer dois:

```
var filmes = [];
$.get("https://www.mocky.io/v2/5ad631b32e00001000c93a96", function(data){
    data.forEach(function(filme){
        filmes.push(filme);
        $.get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${filme}&apikey=???`,function(data) {
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Porque dois loop? Não seria mais simples fazer a segunda requisição direto no loop da primeira em vez de criar um array que vai ser percorrido a seguir

Comment: Vc tem razão... pensei nisso também, mas não quis otimizar... mas vou propor

Comment: da segunda maneira funcionou, mas pq funcionou?, eu tentei fazer sincrona e não deu certo tambem :s

Comment: funcionou porque o primeiro $get já retornou os dados... vc vai conseguir fazer síncrono com $.ajax. Veja nesta resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/232516/8063

Comment: Eu entendi mais o menos o motivo disso tudo, vou dar uma estudada mais a fundo, então tentei com $.ajax  com async false, e n rolou, provavelmente estava fazendo também algo errado por não conhecer muito, mas vou dar uma estudada aqui ^^, obrigado pelas explicações

Comment: Valeu. Se precisar de ajuda tamos aí.